# Only show content slideshow if "slideshow" custom field exists

Tags: custom-field, query

I am developing a theme for general release and there is a large content slideshow on the homepage.

I have included a checkbox meta box in the post edit screen that allows users to determine which posts are featured in the slideshow but I can't figure out exactly how to create a query for this.

The checkbox relates to a custom field called "slideshow"

Here is my slideshow code so far;

```
<div id="slides">
<div class="slides-container">

    <div class="slide-content">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink('');?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('slideshow-thumb');?></a>
        <div class="slide-info">
            <h3><?php $category = get_the_category(); echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($category[0]->cat_ID).'">'.$category[0]->cat_name.'';?></a></h3>
            <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink('');?>"><?php the_title('');?></a></h4>
            <?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); echo string_limit_words($excerpt,70);?>
        </div><!--/.slide-info-->
    </div><!--/.slide-content-->

</div><!--/.slides-container-->
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter on meta values using `query_posts()` or a `new WP_Query()` for example:

```
query_posts( array(
    'meta_key' => 'slideshow', // the custom field key to check
    'meta_value' => '1',       // the value eg. 0 or 1
    'meta_compare' => '='      // check for equivalence
) );

// your loop goes here

wp_reset_query();
```

There is a lot more you can do with meta queries if you take a [look in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) including querying on multiple meta keys and values at the same time.

Comment: Perfect. I've actually used a meta query before, I have no idea why I didn't think of it.

Comment: @dean-elliott one of those "can't see the wood for the trees" moments!